# How to access elements in a popup modal iframe using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to click on an input that dynamically appears when clicking another button on the page. I can see that the input is contained in an iframe tag and have tried to use selenium with `browser.switch_to.frame()` (where browser is my webdriver object) Whether I use the frame's id or the frame's object (which selenium can find) or the frame's index, I get the error message below
I have tried to wait to insure that the popup is visible and active on the webpage. I can switch frames to the other 4 iframes in the page without issue.

**My current round of code looks like this:**

```
        time.sleep(5)
        frames = self.browser.find_elements(*(By.XPATH, '//iframe'))
        if frames[4].is_displayed(): 
            print("frame is displayed")
        wait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frames[4]))
```

**Here is the element (without opening and closing tag):**

```
"iframe id="QuickPopupIframe" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none" src="../Reference_Priority/Reference-Priority-QuickSelector.aspx?Target=ctl00_PageContent_PriorityCode&amp;Formula=MVufX1PgieR56FP4ih%2fB7DmXUWVgW2K7F61ffR%2bNCiA%3d&amp;IndexField=SYGQ1ZIIAsXlmKS73s9dbg%3d%3d&amp;EmptyValue=VMGNuzfo24fWSZTXc2WIC9A6qT5R5C0gEgrksjxUk3M%3d&amp;EmptyDisplayText=PsbWe8ErKzHmHOECyYwb2dswos6g1dh5dGzsQ%2fORFos%3d&amp;Mode=F7zc4UXA5KrLE%2bF%2b%2fEj%2bx335yFqXWI8TM9%2fceff20ZA%3d&amp;RedirectStyle=pIzLWXDCgKbu9KF0MLvFEg%3d%3d"></iframe"
```

**Here is the Error Logged:**

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x036DC628>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such window","message":"no such window\\n  (Session info: chrome=81.0....\n\\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x76FE8494+36]\\n\\tRtlAreBitsSet [0x77424328+136]\\n\\tRtlAreBitsSet [0x774242F8+88]\\n"}}'}
```

**Code:**

```
def check_response(self, response):
    """
    Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

    :Args:
     - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
       object.

    :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
    """
    status = response.get('status', None)
    if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
        return
    value = None
    message = response.get("message", "")
    screen = response.get("screen", "")
    stacktrace = None
    if isinstance(status, int):
        value_json = response.get('value', None)
        if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
            import json
            try:
                value = json.loads(value_json)
                if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                    value = value['value']
                status = value.get('error', None)
                if status is None:
                    status = value["status"]
                    message = value["value"]
                    if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                        value = message
                        message = message.get('message')
                else:
                    message = value.get('message', None)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
    if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
        exception_class = NoSuchElementException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
        exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
        exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
    elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
        exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
        exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
        exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
        exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
        exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
        exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
        exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
        exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
    elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
        exception_class = JavascriptException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
        exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
        exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
        exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
        exception_class = ScreenshotException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
        exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
        exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
        exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
        exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
        exception_class = UnknownMethodException
    else:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    if value == '' or value is None:
        value = response['value']
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, value)
        raise exception_class(value)
    if message == "" and 'message' in value:
        message = value['message']

    screen = None
    if 'screen' in value:
        screen = value['screen']

    stacktrace = None
    if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
        stacktrace = []
        try:
            for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                if line:
                    file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                if 'className' in frame:
                    meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                msg = msg % (meth, file)
                stacktrace.append(msg)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
        raise exception_class(response, message)
    elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        alert_text = None
        if 'data' in value:
            alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
        elif 'alert' in value:
            alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

E       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window
E         (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

.....virtualenvs\tau-intro-selenium-py-t3oVQ3Mp\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:242: NoSuchWindowException

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.switch_to.frame` instead of `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`.

```
time.sleep(5)
frames = wait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe")))
if frames[4].is_displayed(): 
    print("frame is displayed")
    #wait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frames[4]))
self.browser.switch_to.frame(frames[4])
```

Comment: I have tried the driver.switch_to.frame as well and get the same message. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jamie Kook I update the answer to help troubleshoot.  I am thinking `frames[4]` may not be the right index.